# Why would InnoDB either not read or not write the count correctly?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I 'm tasked with maintaining an app which processes "batches" that have "logs". These are stored in MySQL using InnoDB tables, with a `log.batch_id` foreign key linking each batch with its logs.

I recently had to optimize the performance of certain operations, one of which involves getting a list of batches together with each one's log count. This operation used to be implemented as a `LEFT JOIN` grouped by `batch.id`, but the performance was unacceptable so I transitioned to a denormalized state of keeping a `cached_log_count` value with each batch.

Due to how the app goes on about its business, this cached count is only updated once for each batch, shortly after its creation. Pseudocode follows:

```
# there are no logs at all for batch id = 42 at this point
$batch = SELECT * FROM batch WHERE id = 42
BEGIN
    FOR (EACH LOG)
        INSERT INTO log (batch.id, ...) VALUES 42, ...
        # error checking elided
    END FOR
    $logCount = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log WHERE batch.id = 42
    UPDATE batch SET cached_log_count = $logCount WHERE id = 42
COMMIT
```

I expect the above to populate the `log` table and correctly set the `cached_log_count` for the associated batch, and *most of the time* that's indeed what happens. However, every so often I get a batch with `cached_log_count` equal to zero (i.e. what its initial value is on creation) while at the same time the logs show in the database just fine.

What's going on? I don't understand how it's possible for the above to *not* always update the log count correctly. I 've thought about refactoring a bit so that the `SELECT COUNT(*)`/`UPDATE batch` pair is turned into a single `UPDATE ... SELECT`, but that doesn't look like it would help.

Additional information that might be relevant:

- The transaction isolation level in effect is REPEATABLE READ.
- The problem only seems to occur for batches with several thousand logs, but even then it only happens infrequently.

Comment: Why not use a view for your cached_log_count instead? Use group by to roll up by the id. Also, is the invalid count persistent post-insert until the next one?

Comment: @Anthony: I tried that, long story short perf is horrible. I 'm not sure what you mean in the second question -- the count is only written once, so a wrong persisted value will remain wrong forever. It's trivial to fix it after the fact, but I want to get to the bottom of why this happens.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's really going on considering the pseudocode, but it seems like the first `SELECT` should be in the transaction as well.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: What is it that you feel is missing/not clear from the pseudocode? I can add that in. Also, why should the SELECT be inside the transaction? It certainly doesn't look like it would make any difference.

Comment: What about a trigger that auto increments a row for each insert? Also, really not clear how the for each log works. Seems like a level of complexity that could be relevant. My main guess is that because InnoDB doesn't use table locking, that the inserts are not complete when the follow up queries are run. So moving them into the transaction may help if it forces them to run when the previous is completed.

Comment: @Anthony: The foreach is PHP code that takes an array of row data and inserts each one in turn. A trigger would be worse for no benefit (a batch may have 20K logs, why would I increment the counter 20K times instead of just once?) and besides, the question is about how to find the problem. I don't get the reference to follow-up queries -- everything relevant is here, and all of it is inside the transaction.

Comment: I 've thought about refactoring a bit so that the SELECT COUNT(*)/UPDATE batch pair is turned into a single UPDATE ... SELECT, but that doesn't look like it would help --- Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 5.5 or 5.6
Then this can happen due to the following reasons:

- The optimizer might optimize away user-defined variables in some situations, preventing them from doing what you want.
- Order of assignment, and indeed even the time of assignment, can be nondeterministic and depend on the query plan the optimizer chose. The results can be very confusing, as you’ll see later.
- The := assignment operator has lower precedence than any other operator, so you have to be careful to parenthesize explicitly.